# CSS image width with object-fit and aspect-ratio

Tags: html, css, aspect-ratio

The following code:

```html
<img
  width="500"
  style="object-fit: contain; aspect-ratio: 7/5; background-color: orange;"
  src="/images/GqZ8FEkFV-s.webp"
/>
```

Renders:

[image]

The width of the background is `500px`. Due to the `aspect-ratio` scaling, the width of the actual image is less than this, so the background overflows the bounds of the image. If I surround this with a `div` with a style of `display: inline-block` or `width: fit-content;`, the surrounding `div` is `500px` wide, rather than the width of the scaled image.

Is there a way to:

- Make the background conform to the size of the scaled image
- Make a surrounding `div` conform to the size of the scaled image

Comment: I am confused between your use of contain and the aspect ratio. Which do you want?

Comment: How about changing `width="500px"` to `height="500px"`?

Comment: @AHaworth Both. `object-fit: contain` makes the image fit in its container while preserving its aspect ratio. `aspect-ratio: 7/5` sets the aspect ratio to maintain.

Comment: @InSync Good thought. But, no dice.

Comment: An image with an aspect ratio of 7:5 is wider than it is taller, as in width: 700px; height: 500px. However, you are using an image with a height that is greater than its width. Thefore, the browser is widening the image according to your `aspect-ratio: 7/5` declaration

Comment: This is a useful insight. But, if I remove `width=500`, the image width is constrained by the width of its container, and I still see the orange background spilling out the sides. The trouble is that I want the image to resize dynamically as the the user changes the viewport dimensions. So, I don't know ahead of time what the dimensions will be. Only the desired aspect ratio.

Comment: It appears that you don't know the desired aspect ratio because you are here not understanding the issue. The actual aspect ratio of this rabbit photo is 2:3 where its width is two-thirds (66%) of its height. However, you are forcing a 7:5 ratio, causing its width to be 140% of its height. By specifying a width of 500px, the 7:5 aspect ratio is reducing the height from 750px to 357px. The `object-fit: contain` declaration uses the intrinsic aspect ratio of 2:3 to reduce the width of the image to 238px and the remaining width of the `img` element is filled with the background color.

Comment: The aspect ratio is the ratio of the width to the height. Therefore, a ratio of 7:5 gives a width that is 2/5 wider than the height. However, you are here asking how to defeat that aspect ratio. The only way is to use the correct aspect ratio of the image `aspect-ratio: 2/3;`. To allow the image to size properly in narrow viewports, you could use `max-width: 100%;`.

Comment: @TimR You really made me rethink the problem. What I needed was a containing div with `aspect-ratio` set, and `object-fit: contain` on the contained image. CSS is normally outside my wheelhouse, and I'm grateful for people like you who know a lot about it! Thank you so much. If you'd like to turn this into an answer, I'll mark it as correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`aspect-ratio`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/aspect-ratio) property sets a preferred aspect ratio for the box using the specified `width / height`. If you declare `width: 500px; aspect-ratio: 7/5;` the preferred height is calculated to be 357 pixels.

```css
img {
  width: 500px;
  aspect-ratio: 7/5;
  background-color: orange;
  }
```

```html
<img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/A76ff.jpg"
  alt="photo of a black bunny on grass and clover">
```

The [`object-fit`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/object-fit) property sets how the content of a replaced element, such as an `<img>` or `<video>`, should be resized to fit its container. With a value of `contain`, the replaced content is scaled to maintain its intrinsic aspect ratio while fitting within the element's content box. The object will be "letterboxed" if its aspect ratio does not match the aspect ratio of the box.

My screen capture of this photo of a black bunny has an intrinsic width and height of 476x714 pixels. 476 divided by 714 (rounded up) is 0.67, the same as 2/3. Therefore, the intrinsic aspect ratio is 2 to 3.

Consequently, when `object-fit: contain` is added to the declarations for this image, the browser scales the rendered image using its intrinsic aspect ratio with a height of 357 pixels. Therefore, the actual replaced content is letterboxed with a width of 238 pixels; the remaining space of the 500px-wide box is filled with the background color.

```css
img {
  width: 500px;
  aspect-ratio: 7/5;
  object-fit: contain;
  background-color: orange;
  }
```

```html
<img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/A76ff.jpg"
  alt="photo of a black bunny on grass and clover">
```

It's not clear to me exactly what your intentions are other than your mention of wanting the image to resize dynamically to fit the viewport. If you throw in `max-width: 100%`, the image width will be contained to its container, and the height will also scale to the specified aspect ratio.

```css
img {
  width: 500px;
  max-width: 100%;
  aspect-ratio: 2/3;
  object-fit: contain;
  background-color: orange;
  }
```

```html
<img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/A76ff.jpg"
  alt="photo of a black bunny on grass and clover">
```